# How to import the complex xml data into excel

Tags: xml, excel

How to import the xml data into excel which have complex data also like:

```
<company>
  <employee>
  <Name>rock</rock>
  <Designation>E1</designation>
  <Address>
    <Address1></Address1>
    <Address2></Address2>
  </employee>
</company>
```

Comment: Have you tried [From XML Data Import (From Other Sources command button, Get External Data group, Data tab)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-xml-data-HP010206405.aspx#BMimport_an_xml_file_as_external_data_w)

Comment: Your XML is malformed. You are closing a tag that was never open (rock) and opening a tag that is never closed (name).

Comment: And no offense but that seems pretty standard XML to me.